# Delete downloaded message bodies from HDD In Windows Live Mail using Hotmail Account?

Tags: email, windows-live-mail, hotmail

Can downloaded message bodies be deleted from the HDD in Windows Live Mail using a Hotmail/Live e-mail account? I know you can do it with a Gmail account in WLM by right clicking on the inbox, clicking properties, local file tab and clicking remove messages (which deletes the message bodies and not the headers).

Answer (score 0):

Open an Explorer window and enter "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows Live Mail" in the address box. The folder with the locally cached email messages will appear. You can try deleting the messages there.